# AWS for .NET and Unity

Tags: amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine

It's been some time since I used AWS and the AWS Unity package is now deprecated and use of the AWS for .NET is now the option to use for AWS.

What is the best and safest way to connect to AWS service to authenticate? I keep coming across video's where they show how to use something but then say this isn't the advised method for doing this. What is? API Gateway? Are any of the methods available HIPAA compliant from Unity? Seems like putting any kind of config stuff directly into the app isn't the safest. Is there anything in Unity that is similar to say a web.config where it pulls the key's but not discoverable in the project if someone tries to extract APK data? It's is very difficult to find any type of samples or anything for AWS use with unity that isn't from the old package from 5 years ago.

Does anyone know of any good starting points? I can barely find anything on how to even connect to AWS let alone grab a S3 bucket and do anything.